# simple question about url

Tags: html, url, web, hyperlink

Normally in my websites, i always use ajax, and only  is refreshed the div that change for each category of the website. So the url is always www.site.com

But in this url: `http://www.site.com/Services` or  `http://www.site.com/Contacts`

This mean that is omitted the extension (like .html or .php) in .htaccess ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://www.site.com/Services` is usually actually `http://www.site.com/Services/index.html` or `http://www.site.com/Services/index.php` where the index.whatever is left off by default.

Though I'm sure you could do it in .htaccess

Comment: for example in this example: http://www.hmmusica.pt/Apresentacao, if you put .html or .php give an 404 error.

Comment: Not always. It can also be an Apache mod-rewritten URL.

Comment: Or `http://www.site.com/Services/default.aspx` or whatever the server thinks it is.

Comment: yeah, i would think that `http://www.hmmusica.pt/Apresentacao` is using apache one way or another to rewrite the url.

Comment: Looks like it's using Joomla as it's CMS which probably handles the htaccess stuff for them